# keras mask not propagated

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Keras (tensorflow 2.6 backend) masks supposed to propagate through the network, [as mentioned in the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding#mask_propagation_in_the_functional_api_and_sequential_api):

> When using the Functional API or the Sequential API, a mask generated by an Embedding or Masking layer will be propagated through the network for any layer that is capable of using them.

Both `Conv1D` and `GlobalMaxPool1D` support masks but mask is not propagated, as demonstrated by the following example,

1. `model1` applies mask and `GlobalMaxPool1D`
2. `model2` applies mask and `Conv1D`
3. `model3` applies mask and `Conv1D` followed by `GlobalMaxPool1D`

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
import numpy as np

mask_val = 10.
inp = layers.Input(shape = (4,3))
masked = layers.Masking(mask_value = mask_val)(inp)
max_pool = layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(masked)
model1 = keras.models.Model(inputs = inp, outputs = max_pool)
#--- initialize the conv kernel to -1. so it's easy to interpret output
conv = layers.Conv1D(1, 2, padding = 'valid', kernel_initializer = initializers.Constant(-1.))(masked)
model2 = keras.models.Model(inputs = inp, outputs = conv)
out = layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(conv)
model3 = models.Model(inputs = inp, outputs = out)
```

Now test these 3 models on a simple input, 2 samples of dimension 3, followed by 2 masked samples:

```
x0 = np.concatenate((np.ones((1,2,3)), mask_val * np.ones((1,2,3))), axis = 1)
model1(x0) # outputs [1,1,1], as expected
model2(x0) # outputs [-6, -3, 0] as expected
model3(x0) # outputs [0], but should output [-3] as the 0 value should be masked
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

So, I was wrong thinking that `Conv1D` and `GlobalMaxPool1D` support masks. Turns out that:

```
layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D().supports_masking #--- this property is False
layers.Conv1D(1,1).supports_masking          #--- this property is False
```

It **seemed** to support mask since the masking layer replaces the masked values by `0`s, and then the outputs of both the `Conv1D` layer and the `GlobalMaxPooling1D` layer were not affected by these `0`.

A different input (with `-1` instead of `1` as the un-masked values) shows it:

```
x0 = np.concatenate((-np.ones((1,2,3)), mask_val * np.ones((1,2,3))), axis = 1)
l_masked = layers.Masking(mask_value = mask_val)
l_max_pool =  layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()
l_max_pool(l_masked(x0)) #--- returns [0,0,0] - ignoring the mask :(
```